# How do I find the exact total of the cart(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, cart, shopping-cart

I have made an online food ordering website all is done but I don't know I am getting sum BUG in finding the total
The javascript updatecartTotal() method which finds total goes like this

```
   
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var rowvar = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    

    
    for (var i = 0; i < rowvar.length; i++) {
        var rowvar = rowvar[i]
        var priceElement = rowvar.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = rowvar.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('₹', ''))
        var quantity = parseInt(quantityElement.value)
        z = (price * quantity)
        console.log(price)
        console.log(z)
        console.log(quantity)
        total = (Math.round(z*5/100))  + (quantity*total) + (z)
        
        console.log(total)
    }
}
```

I want a gst of 5 percent  **NOT ON ULTIMATE FINAL PRICE**
I want it on final price of each food item then add all final prices to get ULTIMATE FINAL PRICE which is our total.It is quite confusing bug for me hope you can solve it.

Here price is just the price per piece of item

Thank You

Comment: You really haven't explained where you are stuck and what is wrong with your current approach. What exactly do you need from people here? See [ask]

Comment: Also please provide enough sample html to create a [mre]

Comment: Don't dump unformatted code blobs into comments where it is impossible to read and work with. Instead, [edit] the question with that code and further details of what you expect

Comment: `var rowvar = rowvar[i]` - here you reassign the variable, which should break it all. Use another name, like `rowvarItem` for the new variable